# Finding the max of $\lambda$ for $\frac{1}{\lambda} =R\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus

This background of this question is coming from Physics but it's more of a mathematical question. In physics we have the following equation (rydberg ritz equation):
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} =R\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)
$$
where $R>0$ is constant, $m>n$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

After some observations, I think that $\lambda_{\max}$ will happen for $m=n+1$, but I can't seem to figure why and how to prove such theorem. Is it true? If so, is it possible to suggest a proof for that? Is it also true that $\lambda_{\min}=R$?

EDIT: For example, for $n=2$ (Balmer series) we get $\lambda_{\min}=R$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ is when $m=3$.

Comment: The stated relation is dimensionally inconsistent with $\lambda_\min=R$. Further, if $n=m+1$ then $\lambda<0$.

Comment: Without some conditions on m and n, $\frac{1}{\lambda} \to 0$ as both m and n $\to \infty$   As for $\lambda_{min}$, your assertion is correct, since the best you have is m=1 and n $\to \infty$.

Comment: But is not $m>n$ helps us figure out $\lambda_{\max}$?

Comment: concavity is probably the best approach

Comment: Are $m, n$ greater than $0$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla yes,$m,n\geq 1$ due to being natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of $\lambda$ would be at the minimum of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Then to minimize this, $\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2}$ would be minimized over $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m > n$.

If $n$ is fixed, then $\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2}$ is minimized when $\frac{1}{m^2}$ is maximized, or equivalently when $m$ is minimized (within the domain). This in turn happens when $m = n+1$ (which is what you got). Then $\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ approaches $0$ as $n \to \infty$, so $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ could be made to approach $0$. This means that $\lambda$ approaches $\infty$. For a fixed $n$, the maximum would be $$\frac{1}{R} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}$$

Similarly, to minimize the wavelength, maximize $\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2}$. Assuming $n$ is fixed, this is maximized when $m$ is maximized (which could approach $\infty$). Then $\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}$, so $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ approaches $\frac{R}{n^2}$. This means that $\lambda$ approaches $\frac{n^2}{R}$. To minimize this, $n = 1$, giving $\lambda = \frac{1}{R}$. For a fixed $n$, the minimum would be $$\frac{n^2}{R}$$

From a physics standpoint, this makes sense because when an electron jumps fewer levels, it releases less energy. Since energy and wavelength are inversely related, when less energy is released, the wavelength would be higher.